# How can I ensure initialization cells are evaluated in order of definition?

Tags: evaluation, cells, initialization

I have a cell:

```
Unprotect[Plus];
```

followed by a cell:

```
Plus[label[t1_, l1_], label[t2_, l1_]] := label[t1 + t2, l1]
```

If I give the notebook the command "evaluate initialization cells" sometimes this fails as the second cell gets evaluated before the first. I would like an initialization command where the default order of evaluation is the order of definition. Or is there some other solution recommended for this problem?

Comment: I would be very surprised if the cells are not evaluated one after the other in the order given in the notebook (i.e. top down). Unless you are doing something with parallel kernels and such.

Comment: oh, maybe it was because I had another kernel turned on. Tough I'm not doing anything "explicitly" parallel.

Comment: Why couldn't you put both definitions in one cell?

Comment: I actually did do that. But now I'm uncertain as to whether any other parts of the program might be vulnerable to out-of-order initialization bugs.